# Transform pandas dataframe into different format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
             col1  col2  col3  col4
id Category                        
a  blue         4     1     3     0
   red          1     0     0     4
b  red          0     1     8     5
```

which can be made using the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': ['a','a','b'],'Category': ['red','blue','red'], 'col1': [1,4,0], 'col2': [0,1,1],'col3' : [0,3,8], 'col4': [4,0,5]})
sum_df = df.groupby(['id','Category']).agg({'col1': 'sum', 'col2': 'sum','col3': 'sum', 'col4': 'sum'})
```

I want the output to look like this

```
  id  red_col1  red_col2  red_col3  red_col4  blue_col1  blue_col2  blue_col3  blue_col4
0  a         1         0         0         4        4.0        1.0        3.0        0.0
1  b         0         1         8         5        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Where I want every `id` to be unique for a row and the values summed up into respective columns. There are 1000s of ids in the dataset and 1000s of categories too. If a column does not have a value associated with it, then it should be blank i.e. `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then rename columns:

```
new_df = df.unstack('Category')
new_df.columns = [f'{color}_{col}' for col, color in new_df.columns]
new_df=new_df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  id  blue_col1  blue_col2  blue_col3  blue_col4  red_col1  red_col2  \
0  a        4.0        1.0        3.0        0.0       1.0       0.0   
1  b        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       0.0       1.0   

   red_col3  red_col4  
0       0.0       4.0  
1       8.0       5.0
```

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=df.unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format) 
s
Out[136]: 
    blue_col1  blue_col2  blue_col3  ...  red_col2  red_col3  red_col4
id                                   ...                              
a         4.0        1.0        3.0  ...       0.0       0.0       4.0
b         NaN        NaN        NaN  ...       1.0       8.0       5.0
[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Yoben. The solution works but accepted the other one as that was posted before.

Answer (score 0):

Unstack using

```
df = df.unstack()
```

Then you can add the prefix

```
df = df.add_prefix(category'_')
```

This will fix